# I got stuck in fetching data from JSON API, it's little bit complex and nested, I want to Get "resource_uri" from "abilities" Array

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    //I got stuck in fetching data from JSON API, its little bit complex and //nested, anyone plz help me, I want to Get "resource_uri" from "abilities" //Array

    @IBOutlet weak var tblData: UITableView!

    final let urlString = "[https://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/][1]"


    var lableArray = [String]()
    var resource_uri = [String]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let ceL = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CeL") as! Celll

        ceL.lbl.text = lableArray[indexPath.row]
        return ceL
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadJsonWithURL()
    }


    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                //print(jsonDict!)

                for _ in jsonDict!{
                    if let subDict = jsonDict?.value(forKey: "meta") as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = subDict.value(forKey: "next") {
                            self.lableArray.append(name as! String)
                            //print(self.lableArray)

                        }
                    if let actorArray = subDict.value(forKey: "objects") as? NSArray {
                        if let name = actorArray.value(forKey: "abilities") as? NSDictionary {
                            if let name = name.value(forKey: "resource_uri") as? NSArray
                            {
                                self.resource_uri.append(name as! String)
                                print(self.resource_uri)

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tblData.reloadData()
            })
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: whats your json? print it here.

Comment: Please show us a JSON sample too.

Comment: why urlString has [1] it should be     `final let urlString = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/"`

Comment: Also use this resource:
http://json.parser.online.fr/
It will help you understand the whole structure of your json.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex response to parse, and pokeapi allows you to drill down and ge the data you need easier.

However, this part should be an array:

```
if let name = actorArray.value(forKey: "abilities") as? NSDictionary
```

Probably like this:

```
if let dict = actorArray.value(forKey: "abilities") as? [NSDictionary]
```

Then you need iterate through the dict and get the uri someway similar to this:

```
if let dict = actorArray.value(forKey: "abilities") as? NSDictionary {
    for dictionary in dict {
        if let uri = dict["resource_uri"] as? String {
            // Do something with uri here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Past your desired URL(https://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/) to any browser and copy and Past your output (JSON) to [Online JSON Editor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) and analyse what you can convert to model, then create model class(inspired from JSON) and convert and mapped.
2. Quick solution: Pass your result(JSON) to [Object Mapper Github](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) and it will finally give you model or array of models.

Hope this will help. 
Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code to get resource URI and abilities array

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonDict!)

                if let subDict = jsonDict?.value(forKey: "meta") as? NSDictionary {
                    if let name = subDict.value(forKey: "next") {
                        self.lableArray.append(name as! String)
                    }
                }
                if let objectsArray = jsonDict?.value(forKey: "objects") as? NSArray {
                    if let actorArray = (objectsArray.firstObject as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "abilities") as? [NSDictionary]{
                        for dictionary in actorArray {
                            if let uri = dictionary["resource_uri"] as? String {
                                self.resource_uri.append(uri)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                print("resource uri \(self.resource_uri)")
                print("labelarray \(self.lableArray)")
            })

        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: I don't know bro why... :(

Comment: Am not asking you bro @AbdulJabbar

Comment: Bro I have another query, can i Discuss ?

Comment: please go ahead